# How to create a HTML/JS GUI for a Java application?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, html

Recently I created a Java application that is continuosly saving data on a SQLite database, and as far as I am concerned it is possible to create a GUI for that application that runs on the navigator using HTML/JS.

What I think I have to do is create a threaded server on my Java app listening http requests coming from the GUI, that would be periodically request information using AJAX

First I tried to follow this tutorial: [Introduction to Ajax for Java Web Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html#javascript), but the problem was that the only way I could make SQL request was on the Servlet but I am not able to do so (don't know why).

JxBrowser would be the perfect solution but it is not FOSS ...

Is it possible to bridge my application to HTML/JS/CSS ?

Comment: Must be an application? How about JSP web pages?

Comment: Do you mean that the example showed on [this link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html#javascript) could work ? I tried to save the objects on a database on the init() method of the servlet, but it was not working

Comment: Wait. Java is different from JavaScript. Hotdog is not related to Dog, too.

Comment: I know, but it was the first time I was using servlets so I do not know what I am doing wrong